# expand / collapse floated divs on mouseover without falling to the next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for some ideas on how to resolve a little problem I have when expanding divs on mouseover.

I have a series of divs with percentage width floated all to the left. When I move the cursor over one div it will grow 3 times its size, moving all the divs after to the right. Right now, only 4 divs fits on a signgle row, the problem is that when move the mouse over the last two elements of each row, they will fall into the next row since they do not fit anymore in their current row.

Here's an example of what I've been working so far:

css:

```
    #mosaicWrapper{ width:70%; background:#ccc}
   .mosaic{ width:20%; background:#06C; height:150px; float:left; margin:20px 20px 0 0; color:white; text-align:center; font-size:74px; position:relative; cursor:pointer}
```

code:

```
var wrapper = $('#mosaicWrapper');
var mosaic = $('.mosaic');
var mosaicWidth = mosaic.outerWidth(true);
var elesPerRow= Math.floor(wrapper.width()/mosaicWidth);
var expandedWidth = (mosaicWidth*(elesPerRow-1))-mosaic.margin('right');
var lastItems = [];
var intialWidth = mosaic.width();


for (var i = elesPerRow; i < mosaic.length; i = i + elesPerRow){
    var lItem = i - 1;
    lastItems.push(lItem);
}

mosaic.each(function(index, element) {
    thisItem = $(this);
    thisItem.mouseover(function(e) {                
        $(this).stop(false, false).animate({'width':expandedWidth},500);
        if($.inArray(index, lastItems) > -1){
            var last = index - 1;                   
        };
    });

    thisItem.mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).stop(false, false).animate({'width':intialWidth},500);
    });
});
```

example working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjm3h/3/

I had an idea of cutting the previus two divs and pasting them after the current div, without any luck since the cursor losses the div because this one also moves.

Does anyone has an idea on how to resolve that problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...
Get index of hovered element and then animate width of previous element

```
mosaic.each(function(index, element) {
    thisItem = $(this);
    thisItem.mouseover(function(e) {
        mosaic.eq($(this).index()-1).stop().animate({'width':0},500);
        $(this).stop().animate({'width':expandedWidth},500);

        if($.inArray(index, lastItems) > -1){
            var last = index - 1;
        }
    });

    thisItem.mouseleave(function(e) {
        mosaic.eq($(this).index()-1).stop().animate({'width':intialWidth},500);
        $(this).stop(false, false).animate({'width':intialWidth},500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Givi. The only problem with this one is that I can't change the width of the other divs because they all need to be visible, but you have given me a really good idea on how I can fix it. Maybe I can animate the previus width to 0 and then cut and paste it on the next row with the "initialWidth". I'll give it a try and thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! you can try to remove first element and append it as last onmouseover and then onmouseout bring it back